# Merge and join kist of list that already sorted, but with gaps in data in python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I have a weird data import task, where I need to reconstruct the original order of some data based in partial list of it (generated in files from a ancient list with no posibility of get to the inner datastore), where all is in columns:

This represent the order in what each person must be contacted.

```
COLUMN1

MARTHA LOPES PEREZ
LEIMAR CONEO BELTRAN 
ADALGISA CONEO BELTRAN
YESMIS LUZ DEDOLLA
ELIJIO ARROYO DIAZ

COLUMN2

ROBERTO MANUEL VILLEGAS
MARTHA LOPES PEREZ
LUDIS GUERRA CORONADO
PATRICIA FABRA MEDINA
LEIMAR CONEO BELTRAN 
ADALGISA CONEO BELTRAN
YESMIS LUZ DEDOLLA
ELIJIO ARROYO DIAZ
TEOBALDO MONTIEL SALGADO

COLUMN3
LUDIS GUERRA CORONADO
ANDRES ORTEGA DIAZ
PATRICIA FABRA MEDINA
LEIMAR CONEO BELTRAN 
ELIJIO ARROYO DIAZ
TEOBALDO MONTIEL SALGADO
YENIS MONTES ROMEROS
SANTA PEREZ GAVIRIA
```

With this, I need to re-generate the order of it. This is the desired output:

```
ROBERTO MANUEL VILLEGAS (Because is before MARTHA)
MARTHA LOPES PEREZ (Because nobody is behind him)
LUDIS GUERRA CORONADO (Because is after MARTHA)
ANDRES ORTEGA DIAZ
PATRICIA FABRA MEDINA
LEIMAR CONEO BELTRAN 
ADALGISA CONEO BELTRAN
YESMIS LUZ DEDOLLA
ELIJIO ARROYO DIAZ
....
....
```

So the value is compared with the all the columns.

I think this is the sort-merge-join as show on:

http://sqlity.net/en/1480/a-join-a-day-the-sort-merge-join/

I don't need a efficient version, this is only a one-off task.

Comment: What's your question, exactly? I can't tell what you're asking. (I'm also not entirely clear on the meaning of the first code block you posted. Some of the names appear multiple times, so it doesn't make sense as an order, unless some of the people are supposed to be contacted multiple times.)

Comment: Each block is a different list. Is necessary to check each value to each column and output the order according I show in the example.

Comment: How many partial lists are there, and how large are they?

Comment: It vary. The first set are 8.

Comment: What is unclear with this question?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you're looking for is [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Each of your columns defines a dependency relationship among names, and you can put all those dependencies into a graph: each name is a node, and for each pair of consecutive items in a list, there is a directed edge from the first name to the second name (or vice versa, depending on which implementation you use). Just go through each list and create those nodes and edges as you go, then once you're done, run a topological sort algorithm on the resulting graph.

The [toposort package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toposort/1.0) includes a topological sort implementation which is compatible with Python 3 (and 2). It expects a dictionary of sets giving the relationships, which you could construct something like this:

```
graph = collections.defaultdict(set)
for column in columns:
    for first, second in pairwise(column)
        graph[second].add(first)
```

`pairwise` is one of the `itertools` recipies, which you can copy into your code from the package's documentation, or you can use the implementation in the [`more-itertools` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools/). Once you've constructed the graph, use `toposort.toposort_flatten(graph)` to get the names in order.

Note that the output may not be entirely deterministic, because there could be some names with no dependency relationship specified - in other words, there's nothing to tell which one should go first.

Comment: I try this but the toposort package give a error about Cyclic dependencies.

Comment: That means there is no solution to the problem you're described.